# How to generate AAD token using IIS Windows Integrated Authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, windows-authentication

In AS-IS case, all the applications are deployed on private network and only exposed to internal users. Users logged in via their windows system credentials are authorized to call web based application (Angular) deployed on IIS with Windows Integrated feature (kerberos) enabled. Authenticated users further calls the APIs end points. There is no APIs authentication in place as of now.

> Now to place a security around the endpoints, it's recommended to get
>   it authenticated via AAD but it should not prompt user with the login
>   page.
>
> To implement below gist (using Microsoft.Identity.Client library may be), I did not
>   get much documentation or any example around it. How to generate token
>   using WIA?

[image]

Any help on this would be appreciated.

> Is there any way to achieve AAD token using Windows Integrated
>   Authentication? Any suggestions/ way forward to move ahead, any
>   alternate route would work. Any of your thoughts are welcome